How to get macOS to install Sonoma 14.5?
I'm trying to update my M3 to Sonoma 14.5. I currently have 14.4.1.
Usually I see available in the normal spot, in “System Settings -> General -> Software Update.” But regardless of whether I have automatic updates enabled or manual updates, I am told that I am up to date. No option for updating to 14.5 appears. What I see is this:


How did you get 14.4.1 onto your system? Sometimes developer betas can't be upgraded to release versions. By the way, you probably won't be offered 14.5 as it is also out of date. If things were working correctly, you'd be offered 14.6.1 (23G93).

Thanks.  I got 14.4.1 preinstalled.  It's a pretty new laptop.  I was able to get the App Store app to let me try to install the 14.6 version, but it failed while "preparing". Am suspicious something is throwing it off, so going to reboot first.  Thx for helping.  Will be back in a bit.

Problem solved. I shut down MacBook completely. Held power button down until startup options offered (hard disk icon on left and Options icon button on right). I chose Options icon. Then I was offered choices of Restore from Time Machine, Reinstall MacOS and a couple others. I chose Reinstall macOS Sonoma. It took a bit but succeeded. I did have a problem logging in first time in normal mode -- stuck on spinner -- and had to boot into Safe Mode. Things looked fine so I restarted again and was able to log in normally. Sonoma 14.6.1 is installed.

You can use the the free Mist app to download a specific version of macOS installer for in-place system update. Currently, the supported versions are from the oldest OS X Lion 10.7.5 to the latest macOS Sequoia 15.0. Here is the screenshot:

